# How to capture photoshop mouse pointer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to write a tutorial of photoshop techniques. But I am fairly new at this and when i hit print screen it does not copy the mouse cursor.

Does anyone know how to copy the mouse cursor in Photoshop under Windows 7?

Comment: I screenshot the cursor page, cut out the one I need, then add it to my image. Easy enough.

Comment: I think this question is more about operating systems and software and therefore should be migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a third party application such as ScreenshotCaptor (http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/). One of its options is to capture the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

+1 nice question never noticed :|

in fact mouse cursor is absent in normal print screen also :O

why you need mouse cursor to show?? Photoshop does not copy the mouse cursor,it highlights the selected tool, selected layer or anything which is selected, you can draw your own cursor in Photoshop to indicate....

[In most versions of Windows, captured screenshots do not include the mouse pointer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot)

Most famous third party software [gadwin](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) it captures the screen with cursor, make your tutorials with the help of this

Comment: @Jack: I am creating tutorials where i need to show the cursors while using printscreen. I have notice in other tutorial sites that its possible. But don't know how to do that :(

Comment: i dont think so i havnt noticed in any tutorials site,if its is there might be they are using some software sort of thing...lets everyone check, surely will come with  solution

Comment: @Jack: May be they have these cursor icons designed.

Comment: yes i noticed if we take a normal print screen there is no mouse cursor its not related to PS only

Comment: what are you using in window's..? xp or 7?

Comment: @jack: Windows 7

Comment: Read this might be any step can help you out, i doubt you have to use third party software : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/ctrl-print-screen-isnt-capturing-the-cursor/b920d566-ae48-466c-a11b-bddffd70da09

Comment: @Jack: The beta tester's friend, that one.

Comment: @alan dint get you

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two free, web-based tutorial solutions:

1. Skitch,  which includes annotation tools to point to the location you need on the screen.
2. Jing if you want to create short instructional videos that record your screen and voice instructions. It will record your pointer movements while you explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I just take my screenshots and Photoshop in a cursor from [this set](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_liHhcQQA8iA/TD77ueQX9KI/AAAAAAAAAUU/FcB-RWlXvOg/s1600/cursor-white.png). Works great! 
I usually use one that's slightly larger than the actual size just to make it easier to spot.